# How to open bash from executable?

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

I am trying to open a bash shell (in Linux) from inside a C or C++ executable. I tried both languages but the compiled executable is more than 4kb because of the libraries needed to make a system call.

I need to make the executable less or equal to 4Kb. How can i do that?

Comment: 4k isn't that large... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DanFego I am trying to store the executable in a 4Kb buffer(i am trying a security exploit on my machine).

Comment: On a test box I've got, I tried to compile an executable with `-Os` with just a `main()` returning `0`, and it's over 6k. What about some shellcode?

Comment: How big is the application without the system call?

Comment: @DanFego its fine if its shell code as long as its an executable

Comment: @LokiAstari thats it, it just opens up a bash shell

Comment: @MikeG: My point is what is the difference in size from an application with and without the system call. I don't think you will spot much difference.

Comment: @LokiAstari the buffer is strictly 4kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you stripped your program? This example code gives less than 4K both with C and C++:

```
$ cat shell.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("echo hello");
  return 0;
}
$ gcc -o shell shell.c
$ strip -s shell
$ ./shell
hello
$ du -b shell
2836    shell
$ g++ -o shell shell.c
$ strip -s shell
$ ./shell
hello
$ du -b shell
3216    shell
```

Of course you can make executable even smaller. Write it in asm and do not  link any libraries.

Comment: Facepalm. I strip binaries all the time and forgot to do that here.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is exec a shell, compiling

```
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){
    static char* bash[] = {"/bin/bash", NULL};
    execv(*bash, bash);
}
```

With [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/) as `diet -Os gcc test.c` yields an executable of 2929 bytes. Stripping the binary with `strip a.out` yields 1464 bytes. This also has the benefit of being statically linked, which is appropriate for an exploit.